# Java: Function parameter that takes any type

Tags: java, oop

Im writing a Java function to output things to the console with a certain format, but I need one of the parameters to accept any type as an argument. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Generics, it would work as follows:

```
public static <T> void printAnything(T anything){
    System.out.println(anything);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    printAnything(new SyncPart());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generics shown in [SMA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509803/3788176) are unnecessary: just take `Object` as your parameter type:

```
public static void printAnything(Object anything){
    System.out.println(anything);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any type is not possible. Primitives will stop you from what you're doing.

But you can use `void myFunction(Object anyObject) {}` for example, and give it any Class-type = reference-type Object.

If you still wanna include primitives, you have to split up to multiple methods:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class ClassOverload {



    // central method
    static public void myMethod(final Object pObject) {
        final String type = pObject == null ? null : pObject.getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println("ClassOverload.myMethod(" + pObject + ") of type " + type);
    }

    // primitive overloading methods
    static public void myMethod(final boolean pValue) { // absolutely needed
        myMethod(Boolean.valueOf(pValue));
    }
    static public void myMethod(final char pValue) { // absolutely needed
        myMethod(Character.valueOf(pValue));
    }
    static public void myMethod(final byte pValue) {
        myMethod(Byte.valueOf(pValue));
    }
    static public void myMethod(final short pValue) {
        myMethod(Short.valueOf(pValue));
    }
    static public void myMethod(final int pValue) {
        myMethod(Integer.valueOf(pValue));
    }
    static public void myMethod(final long pValue) { // absolutely needed
        myMethod(Long.valueOf(pValue));
    }
    static public void myMethod(final float pValue) {
        myMethod(Float.valueOf(pValue));
    }
    static public void myMethod(final double pValue) { // absolutely needed
        myMethod(Double.valueOf(pValue));
    }



}
```

This will convert your primitives to their reference type and keep the type as close to the original as possible.

If you wanna reduce the methods, you could just keep the `boolean`, `long` and `double` methods. All other primitives can be cast into one of those three:

- `boolean` will use the `boolean` method.
- `char` will use the `char` method.
- `byte`, `short`, `int` and `long` (all "whole number" integer values, as opposed to floating-point values) will use the `long` method.
- `float` and `double` (floating-point) will use the `double` method.

Comment: while this is true, it is unnecessary since Java has Auto-Boxing and unfortunately Auto-Unboxing which can lead to NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Yes. You're right. But who in his right mind allows the use of AutoBoxing and AutoUnboxing in his Java code without having the compiler generate warnings. AutoUnboxing NPE just being one of the many reasons...

Comment: This approach has no problems with auto-unboxing of `null`, as invocations of `myMethod` with a boxed type, e.g. `Integer`, will invoke `myMethod(Object)` which handles `null`. But in the end, all the other methods are just unnecessary. They do manually what auto-boxing does automatically. In fact, they make it worse because you forgot to add a `char` variant. So `char` gets unintentionally converted to `int` and then to `Integer`. While when having only `myMethod(Object)`, `myMethod('A')` would do the right thing.

Comment: Thanx Holger for that insight. Will update my answer.